# How can I parse the year, month, and day out of this string?

Tags: java, parsing

Given a directory name as a string like so:

```
c:\can\be\anything\...\2013\12\01
```

or without the 'day' like so:

```
c:\can\be\anything\...\2011\10
```

How can I easily parse out the year, month, and day into integers:

```
int iYear;
int iMonth;
int iDay;
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

rh

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please (re)read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good SO questions.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I tried something with StringTokenizer but didn't include it so as to simplify the question.  I got some great answers from other users, doesn't that indicate it was a reasonably worded question?

Comment: Presumably you want this to be cross-platform?  So you can split something like `/home/user/anything/2013/12/10` too?  If you need this, then you should create a `File` object from the name, then traverse your way up the directory tree.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks!  That's a good idea and works for me for other reasons.  (And say hi to Michael Scott for me. ;-)

Comment: You may have me confused with someone else.  I don't know a Michael Scott.  ...  Ooh, no maybe you don't.  I've just remembered who YOU are!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Based on Java 1.7 API:

```
String dir1 = "c:\\test1\\2013\\12\\01"; // c:\test1\2013\12\01
String dir2 = "c:\\test1\\2013\\10";     // c:\test1\2013\10

public void getDate(String dir) {
  String parts[] = (java.io.File.separatorChar == '\\' ? dir.split("\\\\") : dir.split("/"));
  int len = parts.length();
  if (len >= 3) {
    int iYear, iMonth, iDay;
    if (parts[len-2].length() == 4) {
      iYear = Integer.parseInt(parts[len-2]);
      iMonth = Integer.parseInt(parts[len-1]);
      iDay = 0;
    } else {
      iYear = Integer.parseInt(parts[len-3]);
      iMonth = Integer.parseInt(parts[len-2]);
      iDay = Integer.parseInt(parts[len-1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Notes:

- Split method of String requires a string of regular expression. Since the elements of directory's name is separated by backslash (`\`) then you have to use string's escaped character (`\\`), plus regular expression's escaped character (`\\\\`).
- Line 4 will retrieve OS's path separator: `\` in Windows, `/` in *nix.
- Line 7 will check whether the date is in first or second form.

Comment: If you have `c:\can\be\anything\...\2011\12\01` then you have to know how many prefix parts of directory path that need to be removed. You just need to change the index value in line 3-5, and the condition as well in the last line.

Comment: I think the new solution (edited) can solve ZouZou's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the string by '\', take the last three, and assign the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.lang.Number;
    import java.lang.String;
    import java.lang.StringBuffer;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    public class Test{
        private static String path = "c:\\can\\be\\anything\\...\\2013\\12\\01";
        public static void main(String[] args){
            String[] tmp = path.split("\\\\");
            if(tmp.length > 3){
                String day = tmp[tmp.length-1];
                String month = tmp[tmp.length-2];
                String year = tmp[tmp.length-3];

                System.out.println(day+" "+month+" "+year);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> public class test {
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub>
>
> ```
>   String test = new String("c:\\can\\be\\anything\\test\\2013\\12\\01");
>   System.out.println("test "+test);
>   String[] result = test.split("\\\\");
>
>     for(String s : result){
>         System.out.println(">"+s+"<");
>     }
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Answer (score -1):

Probably the easiest thing would be to use split("\") then get the strings back as an array and throw out the first n elements until you get to the one with the year.

```
String[] elements = requestUrl.split("\");

int yearIndex;
int monthIndex = yearIndex + 1;
int dayIndex = monthIndex + 1;

for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    int value = Integer.parseInt(element);
    if (value > 1900){
        yearOffset = i;
        break;
    }
}
int year = Integer.parseInt(elements[yearIndex]);
int month = Integer.parseInt(elements[monthIndex]);
int day = Integer.parseInt(elements[dayIndex]);
```

If you know how many elements there will be before the year, you don't have to scan.